# Birational map from elliptic curve keeps smoothness?

Tags: group-theory, curves, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be a elliptic curve that is , genus $1$ smooth curve with base point.
And suppose that the map $φ$, which sends $E$ to $E'$, is birational.
Birational means there are two rational maps on both direction which composites identity.

Then, can we say that $E'$ is smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is distinctly untrue. Indeed, finding a birational map to a smooth curve is often how we deal with singular curves. For a specific counterexample consider $$C : Y^2Z^2 = X^4 + Z^4$$
with the base point $O = [0:1:1]$. Note that $C$ is a singular curve with singular point $[0:1:0]$, the point at infinity.

Then $C$ is birational to the (smooth) elliptic curve
$$E : Y^2Z = X^3 - 4XZ^2$$
with the map given by
$$\phi : [X,Y,Z] \mapsto [2XYZ + 2XZ^2, 4YZ^2 + 4Z^3,X^3]$$

The inverse of $\phi$ is given by
$$ [X,Y,Z] \mapsto [2YZ, X^2 + 4Z^2,X^2 - 4Z^2]$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but is $C$ also elliptic curve?I learned elliptic curve can be also defined as a curve which is birational to weierstrass form. $C$ is birational to the weierstrass form $E$, so from this definition, $E$ is elliptic curve.Also, $C$ has genus 1, but can we say $C$ is elliptic curve although $C$ is not smooth?

Comment: It depends what you take as your convention. Some people will say "an elliptic curve is a curve in weierstrass form" more will say "a smooth genus 1 curve with a marked point", for convinience most say "a curve with geometric genus 1 and a marked non-singular point" - with this last definition $C$ is an elliptic curve. At the end it's just semantics because you can always just normalise if you're really being fussy about smoothness

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. If we assume more condition to this question, like $E'$ is cubic equation, then the statement holds? I think this is true because $E'$ has genus $0$ if we assume it is singular, this contradicts that the fact that birational map keeps genus. Is this correct?

Comment: Well yes, but I think it's easier to say that if a curve has genus $1$ and degree $3$ then it must be smooth since the arithmetic and geometric genus are equal. Moreover a birational map between smooth curves is an isomorphism so it's not really saying anything interesting

Comment: Thank you so much. What is difference between isomorphism and birational? I define both as rational map between projective variety, which has inverse rational map.

Comment: To be an isomorphism both maps must be morphisms, which is a stronger condition than being rational - it must be regular at all points.